# Append class dynamically on varying URI

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a context path `/userlist` and using server side pagination which results in URI like this: `http://localhost:8080/userlist/?pageSize=10&page=2`.
I am trying to append class to this tag using Thymeleaf dynamically.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" th:with="urls=${new String[]{'/userlist','/userlist/*'}}"
        th:classappend="${#arrays.contains(urls, #httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()) ? 'active' : ''}" href="/userlist"
        th:href="@{/userlist}">
        <span class="nav-icon">
            <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="nav-link-text"> Manage Users</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Above works perfectly fine for `userlist` only. But not for `http://localhost:8080/userlist/?pageSize=10&page=2`.

**Question:** What I am missing here?

Comment: `#arrays.contains` only matches strings... it's doesn't have special functionality for wildcard characters like `*`. (Is that what you're expecting to happen when searching the string `'/userlist/*'`?)

Comment: Yes... something like that.

Comment: But wondering if I have condition for `contains` why it is not working by using `/userlist` alone?